# WPF XAML Strange column width behaviour

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

The following DataGrid begins with thin columns then quickly springs out to the defined widths in the XAML below.

How can we make the column widths as described, from the outset, without the initial behaviour?

```
            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Orders}" Name="_dataGridOrders" AutoGenerateColumns="False">

                <DataGrid.Columns>

                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Order Number" Binding="{Binding OrderNumber}" Width="3.3*"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Numeric ID" Binding="{Binding NumericId}" Width="3*"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Ship To" Binding="{Binding ShipTo}" Width="4*"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Order Date" Binding="{Binding OrderDate}" Width="5*"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Calculated Weight" Binding="{Binding CalculatedWeight}" Width="4*"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="# Items" Binding="{Binding ItemsNumber}" Width="3*"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Tracking" Binding="{Binding TrackingNumbers}" Width="6*"/>

                </DataGrid.Columns>

            </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Need some context... sounds like the layout process is re-deciding on the available space to be filled. However, please remove all properties that are not needed to reproduce the problem... we know nothing of things like your `ui:MultiSelectionSyncHandler.ItemFilter` and if it doesn't contribute to the problem we don't want to know. But if it does, you have to include the code.

Comment: Thanks! ... stripped out everything... and changed the widths to constants... it likes that a lot more... but I don't want constants! I think the number crunching is too much to ask, and it wont be my computer either!

Comment: I get something remotely similar (not really what you describe) when I set the data context in the `Loaded` event instead of the constructor or when many items are added. It is related to the RowHeader taking its space only after the first row becomes visible and the scrollbar appearing when items exceed the visible area, taking some space to the left. Both things force a re-layout because available size changes for the columns, but none of them starts with all columns collapsed to the left. You need to show the parent containers of the DataGrid so we know their layout behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing a bit here because you haven't provided all the relevant code, but I feel pretty certain I know what the problem is.

The reason the DataGrid is starting with thin columns that expand to the expected size is that you are going through multipe layout passes on the grid.  This is most likely due to the fact that you are changing the window size after he window becomes visible.  The reason you might do this is to restore the window size to the size of the last execution of the app.  If you do this in the window constructor you will get the flickering you report.  To fix this move the resize code to the window initialized event handler.

So instead of this...

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Rect r = App.Settings.MainWindowBounds;
        Rect desktop = new Rect(SystemParameters.VirtualScreenLeft, SystemParameters.VirtualScreenTop, SystemParameters.VirtualScreenWidth, SystemParameters.VirtualScreenHeight);
        if (desktop.Contains(r) && r.Width > 0.0 && r.Height > 0.0)
        {
            Left = r.Left;
            Top = r.Top;
            Height = r.Height;
            Width = r.Width;
        }
    }
```

Do this...

```
    private void Window_Initialized(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Rect r = App.Settings.MainWindowBounds;
        Rect desktop = new Rect(SystemParameters.VirtualScreenLeft, SystemParameters.VirtualScreenTop, SystemParameters.VirtualScreenWidth, SystemParameters.VirtualScreenHeight);
        if (desktop.Contains(r) && r.Width > 0.0 && r.Height > 0.0)
        {
            Left = r.Left;
            Top = r.Top;
            Height = r.Height;
            Width = r.Width;
        }
    }
```

This is a much more efficient approach since the window initialized handler is called before the layout pass.